# Lists: Handle Vertical Spacing Between Preceding Text and Following Text Separately

Tags: enumitem

As I understand it, the `topsep` in [enumitem package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/) handles the vertical space between the list environment and the *preceding* text. But it also adds the same vertical space to the *following* text. How can I customize those two vertical spaces separately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to use `\after` to add a `\vspace{}` to alter the spacing *after* the list is output.  The first list is the default settings, the second adds a `topsep=1cm` and the third has `topsep=1cm,after=\vspace*{-1cm}`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand*{\MyText}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam aliquet, orci ut scelerisque eleifend, elit metus commodo eros, sollicitudin euismod lectus tortor at nunc.}

\begin{document}
\MyText
\begin{itemize}
    \item First
    \item Second \hfill\textbf{default settings}
    \item Third
\end{itemize}
\MyText
\begin{itemize}[topsep=1cm]
    \item First 
    \item Second \hfill\textbf{topsep=1cm}
    \item Third
\end{itemize}
\MyText
\begin{itemize}[topsep=1cm,after=\vspace*{-0.75cm}]
    \item First 
    \item Second \hfill\textbf{topsep=1cm, after=\textbackslash vspace*\{-0.75cm\}}
    \item Third
\end{itemize}
\MyText
\end{document}
```